# Adding languages to android emulator

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

I'm creating an app in android studio. I have added a translation for Persian language (Farsi).

But as I'm trying to test it, this language does not exist in the emulator's exiting languages.

Is there a way to add new languages to the emulator?

Comment: AFAIK, as of Android 5.1, Android supports Persian, Persian (Afghanistan) and Persian (Iran).

Comment: Simply use an emulator which has Android 5.1+.

Answer (score 0):

Open **Setting** app from emulator and follow the below path to add Persian keyboard layout:

> Setting --> System -->Languages and Input -->Languages --> Add a
>   language

Search for Persian, 'فارسی' will appear and you can add Persian keyboard layout :)